# SQL Server query is running very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The below query that I'm executing through SQL Server Management Studio is painfully slow.

The input table `tbl_sb12_bhs` has about 40000 records and after an hour only 40 records are processed.

What can be changed here to make this run a bit faster?

```
DECLARE @bsrange INT

SET @bsrange = 0

WHILE @bsrange <= (SELECT max([p_a_l_out])
                   FROM   [DB001].[FD\f7].[tbl_sb12_bhs])
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO [FD\f7].tbl_sb13_b_lin1
                  (aId,
                   p_a_l_out,
                   bs_id,
                   bs_db,
                   bs_tbl,
                   bs_column,
                   Int1,
                   cd1,
                   Hop1,
                   Int2,
                   cd2,
                   Hop2,
                   Int3,
                   cd3,
                   Hop3,
                   Int4,
                   cd4,
                   Hop4,
                   Int5,
                   cd5,
                   Hop5,
                   Int6,
                   cd6,
                   Hop6,
                   Int7,
                   cd7,
                   Hop7,
                   Int8,
                   cd8,
                   Hop8,
                   Int9,
                   cd9,
                   Hop9,
                   Int10,
                   cd10,
                   Hop10,
                   Int11,
                   cd11,
                   Hop11,
                   Int12,
                   cd12,
                   Hop12,
                   Int13,
                   cd13,
                   Hop13,
                   Int14,
                   cd14,
                   Hop14,
                   Int15,
                   cd15,
                   Hop15,
                   Int16,
                   cd16,
                   Hop16)
      SELECT DISTINCT tbl_sb12_bhs.aId,
                      tbl_sb12_bhs.p_a_l_out,
                      tbl_sb12_bhs.bs_id,
                      tbl_sb12_bhs.bs_db,
                      tbl_sb12_bhs.bs_tbl,
                      tbl_sb12_bhs.bs_column,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl.pt_el_Int    AS Int1,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl.user_cd      AS cd1,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl.cfk_upel     AS Hop1,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_1.pt_el_Int  AS Int2,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_1.user_cd    AS cd2,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_1.cfk_upel   AS Hop2,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_2.pt_el_Int  AS Int3,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_2.user_cd    AS cd3,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_2.cfk_upel   AS Hop3,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_3.pt_el_Int  AS Int4,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_3.user_cd    AS cd4,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_3.cfk_upel   AS Hop4,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_4.pt_el_Int  AS Int5,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_4.user_cd    AS cd5,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_4.cfk_upel   AS Hop5,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_5.pt_el_Int  AS Int6,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_5.user_cd    AS cd6,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_5.cfk_upel   AS Hop6,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_6.pt_el_Int  AS Int7,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_6.user_cd    AS cd7,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_6.cfk_upel   AS Hop7,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_7.pt_el_Int  AS Int8,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_7.user_cd    AS cd8,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_7.cfk_upel   AS Hop8,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_8.pt_el_Int  AS Int9,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_8.user_cd    AS cd9,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_8.cfk_upel   AS Hop9,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_9.pt_el_Int  AS Int10,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_9.user_cd    AS cd10,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_9.cfk_upel   AS Hop10,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_10.pt_el_Int AS Int11,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_10.user_cd   AS cd11,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_10.cfk_upel  AS Hop11,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_11.pt_el_Int AS Int12,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_11.user_cd   AS cd12,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_11.cfk_upel  AS Hop12,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_12.pt_el_Int AS Int13,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_12.user_cd   AS cd13,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_12.cfk_upel  AS Hop13,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_13.pt_el_Int AS Int14,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_13.user_cd   AS cd14,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_13.cfk_upel  AS Hop14,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_14.pt_el_Int AS Int15,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_14.user_cd   AS cd15,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_14.cfk_upel  AS Hop15,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_15.pt_el_Int AS Int16,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_15.user_cd   AS cd16,
                      tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_15.cfk_upel  AS Hop16
      FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT pk_a AS aId,
                              p_a_l_out,
                              bs_id,
                              bs_db,
                              bs_tbl,
                              bs_column,
                              hop_pt_id_1,
                              hop_pt_id_2,
                              hop_pt_id_3,
                              hop_pt_id_4,
                              hop_pt_id_5,
                              hop_pt_id_6,
                              hop_pt_id_7,
                              hop_pt_id_8,
                              hop_pt_id_9,
                              hop_pt_id_10,
                              hop_pt_id_11,
                              hop_pt_id_12,
                              hop_pt_id_13,
                              hop_pt_id_14,
                              hop_pt_id_15,
                              hop_pt_id_16
              FROM   [FD\f7].tbl_sb12_bhs
              WHERE  [p_a_l_out] >= @bsrange
                     AND [p_a_l_out] < ( @bsrange + 1 )) AS tbl_sb12_bhs
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_1 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_1
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_2 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_1.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_2
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_3 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_2.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_3
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_4 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_3.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_4
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_5 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_4.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_5
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_6 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_5.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_6
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_7 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_6.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_7
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_8 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_7.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_8
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_9 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_8.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_9
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_10 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_9.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_10
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_11 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_10.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_11
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_12 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_11.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_12
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_13 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_12.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_13
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_14 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_13.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_14
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_15 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_14.sk_el_pt
             LEFT JOIN tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl AS tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_15
               ON tbl_sb12_bhs.hop_pt_id_16 = tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl_15.sk_el_pt

      SET @bsrange = @bsrange + 1
  END
```

Comment: Normalize the tables to have 16 rows per entity joined on tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl once, instead of 16 columns joined on tbl_rpt_val_pt_crl 16 times.

Comment: Think of a way to run a single insert quey without the loop.

Comment: Can you (try to) throw the results into a #temp table...then insert ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that it's slow because you're doing a number of intensive operations all in one go. Without any sample data it's tough, but I can try to make a few suggestions.

From what you said about it only processing 40 records after an hour, it's what's going on inside the loop that's slowing you down.

SELECT DISTINCT isn't cheap because it has to compare all the data, and you're comparing quite a lot of columns as well. If you can, it might run quicker if you limit the number of columns to the bare minimum required for a distinct selection then self joining that to the original table. It should be simple enough to test in isolation to the rest of it to make sure you're getting the same results and whether or not it's quicker.

Also the more joins you have, the worse the performance is in general... the price we pay for normalisation.

Anyway, I would take a step back from it and try to break this down into its smallest units of work and then you can test each one individually until you find the culprit. In doing so, you might think of a much better way to do this. Again, without any sample data this is a difficult one for me to help with.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have an index or indexes on the target then SQL will reindex every row. I'd disable any indexes on the target table and then renable them when the insert is complete. Id batch the inserts inro ranges of (say) 5k records so any blocking will be reduced, or I'd create a temp file as a result of the select and bcp in the results. Because your doing that horrendous set of left joins each time prior to one record insert. SQL just cant optimise more than about 7 or 8 left or right joins. My guess is that there are little or no indexes on the table being inserted from which means a table scan on for each join or around 17 tables scans for each one row inserted. Sorry but this approach is wrong at every stage. Or you could get you boss to buy you a datecentre....

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you might want to do is do the join initially into a temp table and then reference that. You would not have to do the distinct or joins every time. Just add the where clause for the bsrange.

So it would be something like:

```
Create temporary table with as much of the joins/distinct as you can.
while.....
   insert into [FD\f7].tbl_sb13_b_lin1
       select * from temptable where  [p_a_l_out] >= @bsrange
                     AND [p_a_l_out] < ( @bsrange + 1 )
```